# Filter on a single column value using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've created an AngularJS application with a input for filtering the `<tbody>`'s `<tr>`.

Right now my table is filtering on both Country and City - I want it to only filter on Country. I've tried a lot of variations of `filter:{Country: Search}` but it doesn't seem to be working.

> Thanks to user **edisoni.1337** I have an updated working example using AngularJS 1.2.1 (the one seen below).

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('callCtrl', function($scope)
{
 $scope.stuff = [{"House": {"Country": "Denmark", "City": "Copenhagen"}}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="callCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="Search">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>City</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in stuff | filter : {'House.Country' : Search}">
    <td>{{x.House.Country}}</td>
    <td>{{x.House.City}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

## CDN for 1.5.6:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8530/)

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in stuff | filter : {'House.Country' : Search}">
    <td>{{x.House.Country}}</td>
    <td>{{x.House.City}}</td>
 </tr>
```

> Also read this article for better understand
>   http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_filter.asp

Comment: Very odd - your example seems to be working on jsfiddle, but I can't get it to work locally, although the code is identical. Any clues?

Comment: I see now for some reasons this works only with angular js 1.0.1 the version that you have included in the jsfiddle.

Comment: I think that this is because of that multidimensional array that you are using because i try with one dimensional array and it works perfectly

Comment: @Daniel this works perfectly in angular js 1.2.1 include that on your external script source

Comment: in local system, this code doesn't work but if you change it a little, it works like a charm!
instead of filter : {'House.Country' : Search}
use : filter : {'Country' : Search}

Answer (score 1):

This works on 1.5.6 with few changes on the code above: http://jsbin.com/zuxokuy/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Great - Actually I just had to change my search to `<input type="text" ng-model="Search.House.Country">` and filter to `filter : Search` and then it worked! Thank you very much!